# Update with alias in mysql

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql

I am trying to update the record using alias but it gives me error.

The SQL query is the following:

```sql
UPDATE file_associations as fa
SET fa.scheduled_charge_id = NULL 
WHERE fa.faid IN(
  SELECT faid
  FROM file_associations as fa
  JOIN maintenance_requests mr ON ( mr.cid = fa.cid
    AND mr.id = fa.maintenance_request_id ) 
  JOIN scheduled_charges sc ON ( sc.cid = fa.cid
    AND sc.scid = fa.scheduled_charge_id ) 
  WHERE fa.cid =235
    AND fa.scheduled_charge_id IS NOT NULL 
    AND fa.maintenance_request_id IS NOT NULL 
    AND fa.faid IN ( 1, 7 )
);
```

Error is:

> #1093 - You can't specify target table 'file_associations' for update in FROM clause

Can anybody please help me to update record using alias.

Comment: What about trying to remove `as` on your first line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don't use a `where in select`, use a `join` instead

```
update 
  (select faid
   from 
     file_associations as fa
     join maintenance_requests mr on ( mr.cid = fa.cid and mr.id = fa.maintenance_request_id ) 
     join scheduled_charges sc on ( sc.cid = fa.cid and sc.scid = fa.scheduled_charge_id ) 
   where
     fa.cid =235
     and fa.scheduled_charge_id is not null 
     and fa.maintenance_request_id is not null 
     and fa.faid in ( 1, 7 )
  ) s
  join file_associations as fa using (faid)
set fa.scheduled_charge_id = null
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the same table in the `where` condition that in the `from` statement. You must use an alias as you say:

```
UPDATE file_associations as fa
SET fa.scheduled_charge_id = NULL 
WHERE fa.faid IN(
SELECT batman.faid FROM (
 SELECT faid
 FROM file_associations as fa
 JOIN maintenance_requests mr ON ( mr.cid = fa.cid
 AND mr.id = fa.maintenance_request_id ) 
 JOIN scheduled_charges sc ON ( sc.cid = fa.cid
 AND sc.scid = fa.scheduled_charge_id ) 
 WHERE fa.cid =235
 AND fa.scheduled_charge_id IS NOT NULL 
 AND fa.maintenance_request_id IS NOT NULL 
 AND fa.faid
 IN ( 1, 7 )
) as batman
);
```